# Mongoid observers not firing at all (rails 3.2.13, mongoid 3.1.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I think I followed the description of how to make observers exactly,  Model page:

```
class Page
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String
end
```

I have an observer (app/observers/page_observer.rb):

```
class PageObserver < Mongoid::Observer
  observe :page # just to be sure!

  def initialize
    puts "Page observer initialized"
  end
  def after_update page
    puts "After update page "+page
  end
end
```

I added it to config/application.rb:

```
config.mongoid.observers = :page_observer
```

Then when I do `rails c`, I get:

```
$ rails c
Page observer initialized
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
1.9.3p194 :005 > p = Page.first
 => #<Page _id: 5174ce01681167de23000001, title: "Hi", content: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :006 > p.title = "Hi1"
 => "Hi1" 
1.9.3p194 :007 > p.save
 => true
```

Shouldn't I have seen a "After update page " when I `p.save`?

Full code of this simplified example: https://github.com/dts/mongoid_observer_test

Answer (score 0):

Rails Models are not loaded until they are needed, but you cannot register an observer on a class that hasn't been loaded yet, so you will need to forcibly load the Page class first.  Try adding `require File.expand_path('../../app/models/article', __FILE__)` to  `application.rb` after all the other files are loaded, i.e. after `if defined?(Bundler) ... end`

Comment: No dice:  `/Users/dstaudigel/Documents/sources/mongoid_observer_test/config/application.rb:11:in 'require': cannot load such file -- models/page (LoadError)`